Solve the PDE using Direct Integration
Question: Solve for $z(x,y)$ using direct integration
$\frac{\partial{^2z}}{\partial{x^2}} = a^2z$
with the conditions
$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}(0,y)=a\sin (y)$
$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}(0,y)=0$
I am confused on what to do with the $z$ on the right hand side. Do I separate by variables or leave it as it is?
This is what I solved.
Integrate w.r.t $x$
$\int\frac{\partial{^2z}}{\partial{x^2}}dx = \int a^2zdx$
$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}=a^2xz+f(y)$
Apply the first condition
$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}(0,y)=f(y)=a\sin y$
$\implies f(y)=a\sin y$
$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}=a^2xz+a\sin y$
My question is whether I should have removed $z$ from the right hand side before solving the question
The final answer I got is $$z=\frac{2ax\sin(y)}{2-a^2x}$$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@SigmaAlgebra, please look at it again. I have updated the question

$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}=a^2xz+f(y)$ is false because $\int zdx\neq xz$ .

@JJacquelin, so how do I separate z from a^2?

One cannot directly. See my answer for the hint.

It's worth clarifying what the notation "$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(0,y)$" means.  It means compute the derivative $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$, then specialize $x = 0, y = y$.  It does not mean specialize first, then differentiate.

@EricTowers yes, that is what I did. Then, after finding $z$, I differentiate with respect to $y$ to apply the second condition?

@esssystephen   With seperation of variables, i.e. assuming solutions of the type $z(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$, you should end up with $z(x,y) = f(y)\cosh(ax) + g(y)\sinh(ax)$, where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions to be determined with the help of the boundary conditions.

@Abezhiko, if I did that, would it still be direct integration?

See  Airy function

For more direct approach note that the solution of the ODE $f''(x)=a^2f(x)$ obviously is $f(x)=c_1e^{ax}+c_2e^{-ax}$.

$$\frac{\partial{^2z}}{\partial{x^2}} = a^2z \quad\implies\quad  2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2a^2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)^2=a^2z^2+f(y)$$
Can you continue?

I think you multiplied through by $\frac{2\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}$ and then integrated?

@esssystephen. Of course.
